# Uppercase a List of object with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the code below. I'd like to convert all items in this list to uppercase.

Is there a way to do this in Linq ?

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    List<Person> myList = new List<Person>{ 
        new Person { FirstName = "Aaa", LastName = "BBB", Age = 2 },
        new Person{ FirstName = "Deé", LastName = "ève", Age = 3 }
    };
}
```

**Update**

I don't want to loop or go field by field. Is there a way by reflection to uppercase the value for each property?

Comment: You can use List.ForEach for that but this is only the replacement of a foreach loop. Linq is not about making changes to your data objects but making queries.

Comment: Why not normalize the name during object creation?

Comment: @Kris-I: why you need such generic approach, do you have tons of objects and you won't writing for each one special loop/method to upper case strign properties?

Comment: @Kris-I: your update does not make any sense. If you have N objects with M properties, you will need call a method which will *loop* at least `MIN(N,M)` times making `M*N` method calls. Even with reflection you will loop...

Comment: Can we have a clarification here?  Sounds like you want a generic method to do the job for you, do you wish it to alter the underlying data or do you wish it to provide a new item?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why would you like to use LINQ?

Use `List<T>.ForEach`:

```
myList.ForEach(z =>
                {
                    z.FirstName = z.FirstName.ToUpper();
                    z.LastName = z.LastName.ToUpper();
                });
```

---

EDIT: no idea why you want to do this by reflection (I wouldn't do this personally...), but here's some code that'll uppercase all properties that return a string. Do note that it's far from being perfect, but it's a base for you in case you really want to use reflection...:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public static class MyHelper
{
    public static void UppercaseClassFields<T>(T theInstance)
    {
        if (theInstance == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        foreach (var property in theInstance.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            var theValue = property.GetValue(theInstance, null);
            if (theValue is string)
            {
                property.SetValue(theInstance, ((string)theValue).ToUpper(), null);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void UppercaseClassFields<T>(IEnumerable<T> theInstance)
    {
        if (theInstance == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        foreach (var theItem in theInstance)
        {
            UppercaseClassFields(theItem);
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> myList = new List<Person>{
            new Person { FirstName = "Aaa", LastName = "BBB", Age = 2 },
            new Person{ FirstName = "Deé", LastName = "ève", Age = 3 }
        };

        MyHelper.UppercaseClassFields<Person>(myList);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but no properties by properties, or loop. See my update1

Comment: @BobVale Yes it will. As it'll throw an exception if a property has no setter. It's an idea, not a copy-paste-ready solution ;)

Comment: Also why the double generics?  Can you not just declare the signature `public static void UppercaseClassFields<T>(IEnumerable<T> theInstance)`

Comment: @BobVale Completely agree for the double generics. Editing the code example.

Comment: Overload `UppercaseClassFields<T>(T theInstance)` would be helpful as well :)

Comment: @sll You're right, I provided some overload for non-IEnumerable objects :)

Comment: Ideally for performance you'd construct an compiled action using Linq.Expressions that would update the data.  This means reflection would only need to be used once... Wonder if this is the origin of the Linq in in the question

Answer (score 4):

LINQ does not provide any facilities to update underlying data. Using LINQ, you can create a new list from an existing one:

```
// I would say this is overkill since creates a new object instances and 
// does ToList()
var updatedItems = myList.Select(p => new Person 
                              {
                                FirstName = p.FirstName.ToUpper(), 
                                LastName = p.LastName.ToUpper(), 
                                Age = p.Age
                              })
                         .ToList();
```

If using LINQ is not principal, I would suggest using a `foreach` loop.

**UPDATE:**

Why you need such solution? Only one way of doing this in generic manner - reflection.

Comment: @davenewza that's not a LINQ method.

Comment: Right, this is a case (not LINQ one)

Comment: @Jesse: Correct, but it's an additional option to the two which sll proposed.

Comment: Thanks but no properties by properties, or loop. See my update1

Comment: Why are You calling ToList() at the end?? It will execute the query immediately! The reason why Linq is so beautiful is because it is built upon "yield return" of "foreach". Almost each linq method returns IEnumerable (IQuerable) which allows You to chain many methods and the query will not get executed until You will need to iterate over that IEnumerable (IQuerable) or untill You call ToList(), ToArray(), AsEnumerable() etc explicitly (in this case You loose magic of "yeild return")

Comment: @Aleksei: Sometimes you have to execute a linq query immediately to do a snapshot of a data set and return to a caller, sometimes you need `ToList()` to conform with an existing API return/input data type. In this case it is to conform with an example in original question which uses `List<Person>`, possilbel overkill of `ToList()` is the comment.

Answer (score 3):

the Easiest approach will be to use `ConvertAll`:

```
myList = myList.ConvertAll(d => d.ToUpper());
```

Not too much different than `ForEach` loops the original list whereas `ConvertAll` creates a new one which you need to reassign.

```
var people = new List<Person> { 
    new Person { FirstName = "Aaa", LastName = "BBB", Age = 2 },
    new Person{ FirstName = "Deé", LastName = "ève", Age = 3 }
};
people = people.ConvertAll(m => new Person 
         {
             FirstName = m.FirstName?.ToUpper(), 
             LastName = m.LastName?.ToUpper(), 
             Age = m.Age
         });
```

to answer your update

> I don't want to loop or go field by field. Is there a way by
>   reflection to uppercase the value for each property?

if you don't want to loop or go field by field.
you could use property on the class to give you the Uppercase like so

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string FirstNameUpperCase => FirstName.ToUpper();
    public string LastNameUpperCase => LastName.ToUpper();
}
```

or you could use back field like so

```
public class Person
{
    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName {
        get => _firstName.ToUpper();
        set => _firstName = value;
    }

    private string _lastName;
    public string LastName {
        get => _lastName.ToUpper();
        set => _lastName = value;
    }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only really use linq to provide a list of new objects

```
var upperList = myList.Select(p=> new Person {
   FirstName = (p.FirstName == null) ? null : p.FirstName.ToUpper(),
   LastName = (p.LastName == null) ? null : p.LastName.ToUpper(),
   Age = p.Age
   }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks but no properties by properties, or loop. See my update1

Answer (score 0):

```
p.lastname.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(TextString)
```